# Reloading nginx configuration: nginx failed

Tags: nginx

Why does not the nginx rewrite?
"[FAIL] Reloading nginx configuration: nginx failed!"

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/test.php http://domain.com:$1/;test.php last;
```

Destination address:

```
http://domain.com:1234/;test.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this syntax you will always have error
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "test.php" 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

all text after

> http://domain.com:$1/;

this is new directive.
In your example **test.php** == directive, the same as **server_tokens** or **keepalive_timeout**.

So, if you want that your rewrite will be correct use this syntax

> rewrite '^/([0-9]+)/test.php' 'http://domain.com:$1/;test.php' last;